# API REST requests with C#, I hardcoded the URL, but I have several URL on my database that I want to retrieve it from?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

This is my API request, I want to get the URL from my database. In here I hardcoded it but I want to make it dynamic, If you can please help me and I will be appreciated.

```
public static string APICall(string jsonData)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://url.com");

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    //new RestRequest("resource", Method.POST);          
    request.Parameters.Clear();
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    // more code...
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't this question just boil down to "how do I retrieve a string from a database"? How is it relevant what you want to use it for?

Comment: You're already accessing your api... so just save the URLs to your database, and create a new endpoint in your API that would feed you the correct URL based on some parameter.  But... I'd ask yourself if maybe it's better to simply call on that static endpoint, and let the API determine what kind of data to return.  This would invert control/maintenance to the API and not have to do it here in your apicall method.

Comment: I have multiple format Type on my database and each one of them have different url, according to that I need to get the specified url for this format type.

Comment: uRequest.regURL = (string)dr["regURL"];
This ["regURL"] is a column on my database, and I got the right url on this step, but I didn't know how to put it instead of the hardcoded url

Comment: Am I missing something here?  `new RestClient(uRequest.regURL);`  or `new RestClient((string)dr["regURL"]);`

Comment: uRequest is a list that  I created and I was just trying to add that field on it, which is the regURL frim my database.